# SASS Imported file not compiling

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am working on a Laravel 5.5 project with Bootstrap 4. When I compile SASS it returns me that everything it's ok but the imported CSS file is not being watched by SASS.

I have this file ***/resources/assets/sass/app.scss***:

```
// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Bootstrap Toggle
// @import "/resources/assets/css/bootstrap-toggle.css"

// CSS
@import "/resources/assets/css/app.css" <- I want this file to be compiled
```

When I compile SASS with `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` and I save the previous file the console shows me how it is compiled successfully like this:

[image: Console]

As a test, when I change "app.css" to "app.csss", the console displays an error when compiling, so the file it is being loaded.

But when I save something in that file **app.css** nothing changes, I've tried even to clear the browser's cache but the console shows me nothing. So the file is not being compiled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need to use Bootstrap 4 beta, the release version was announced yesterday.

Comment: That was really helpful, thank you.....

Comment: What does your npm scripts look like for dev and watch?

Comment: Of course... that image I added is the result of `npm run watch` or `npm run dev`

Comment: when I change "app.css" to "app.csss"- should be  "app.scss",

Comment: It was a test to realize if the file **app.css** was being well read. It should be **app.css**.

Comment: I think JamesFooks is right, for the compiling to work your file should be named **app.scss** and your import @import "/resources/assets/css/app" ; your compiler will probably ignore .css file changes.